# How to stop ReSharper fading unreachable code?

Tags: configuration, resharper

Very simple question: is there a way of stopping ReSharper fading unreachable code, and if so, how?  It's extremely annoying; sometimes when debugging I *want* to temporarily make code unreachable, yet I still want to see it clearly and maybe edit it.  I can't seem to find a configuration option to stop the fading happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options -> Code Inspection -> Inspection Severity
in search box write "unreachable code" and set level to "Do not show" for your language

Comment: This does actually work, although you need to select "do not show" for *all* the unreachable code inspections (3 were found in my case).  It's still annoying that you can't switch it to the green underline, though - this way it gives you absolutely no warning about unreachable code.  I think I still prefer it to the code fading, though.